# How to deploy swing application on web browser?

Tags: java, swing, browser, jframe, webswing

I have a big swing application that I have developed. There are several classes that each creates its own **JFrame** while closing the previous one which called this class.

I wish to deploy this into a web browser and understand that I need to convert it to an applet. Do I have to add in code for creating applet in each of these classes? or is there some other way.

In my current situation each of the class creates a **JFrame** which has some buttons which on being clicked will close the current **JFrame** and instantiate a new class which creates another **JFrame**.

Could you please help me and advice me on how to resolve my problem?

Comment: No modern browser seems to support Java applets, and Java Web Start is deprecated (and not necessarily a good solution anyway), so Webswing (described below) is about the only viable game in town. It seems to be engineered very professionally, but still has free GPL options.

Answer (score 6):

I have just used below steps:

1. Download **Webswing** from http://webswing.org/
2. Upload your jar file
3. Add your application to `webswing.config` and use Java 8+
4. Start Webswing server and the added application swing window will appear in your browser at http://localhost:8080/ by default

Answer (score 2):

Look into [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html).  This enables you to launch a Swing app from the web without changing a thing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download creamtec.com-->AjaxSwing application
2. Install this application in your system
3. configure java in SetEnv.sh file and also configure the Ajaxswing application path
4. Presently ajaxswing application launched.
5. AjaxSwing > webapps > lib > paste your jar file and related images also
6. To create configure file in Ajaxswing > config > this configure file name should be same on your package name
7. run ajaxswing application
8. select new
9. type project name
10. add related lib file (The all related jar connectors and jar files)
11. type packagename.mainclass
12. run server
13. The system display the url and also launch in ie