# Swing JFrame not displayed

Tags: java, swing, wildfly

I try to execute a java swing jar with a JFrame from a webapp like this :

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar my_swing_app.jar");
```

My app starts (logs are ok) but my jframe doesn't appear. When I run the swing app with powershell, there is no problem.

I try to execute this jar in a java web application that runs in Wildfly server.

Any idea ? Thx.

**UPDATE**

I tried with another command (without java swing app) :

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\test\\build.bat");
```

The result is the same. I can see the process on the windows process list (build.bat) but the command prompt doesn't appear.

Comment: You're trying to run a desktop app from within a web server, I assume you're expecting it to appear on the client computer?  It's probably appearing on the server's computer

Comment: I forgot to mention that the web server and client are in the same computer

Comment: I think you need an applet embedded in html instead

Comment: You may want to look at [this stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979140/swing-application-on-web-browser), it may provide a direction to solve your problem.

Comment: My swing application is used to update my webapp (stop wildfly, reload war etc ...). So , I think, I need an external app.

Comment: You web server might be in headless mode, although I'd expect it to throw an `Exception` then

Comment: No exception in Wildfly logs. What do you mean when you said "headless mode" .

Comment: It is highly likely that WildFly has started with the `-Djava.awt.headless=true` property set. This means that the JVM won't run any graphical components.

Comment: Why do you want to use WildFly for this in the first place? A Java EE application server isn't really built for this sort of thing.

Comment: I have a web app that is running on Wildfly. Sometimes, users can update this application (a new version is available). To do that, I need to execute tasks like download new version, deploy new war, restart server etc... So, I have an exteral standalone jar that I need to execute (with java swing for progress bar, update logs etc..)

Comment: I add "-Djava.awt.headless=true" to wildfly java_opts and it works. Thanks to MadProgrammer and Mike !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the 'java -jar my_swing_app.jar' is getting interpreted as a single command. Instead try

```
            String[]cmd={nativeConverterCommand,tmpHtmlFilePath,tmpPDFFilePath};
        Process wkhtmltopdf=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Refer [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String[]%29)

The first string is the command, the 2nd and third arguments.

Comment: Thanks but the command semms to work well. Indeed, I can see java process in the process list (same result with the string array).