# How to upload jar files in webswing?

Tags: java, swing, webswing

I want to convert my Swing application to web application. Getting help from [How to deploy swing application on web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14979140/418556)

Please have a look to second step of first answer (*"Install this [AjaxSwing] application in your system"*). Where can I upload jar file and how?

Comment: You can go through the Webswing documentation here: https://www.webswing.org/docs/

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually upload a jar file, I think the related answer is misleading. Webswing is a software you download and install on-premise. It starts a web server which serves your application on a web page. All you need to do is create a configuration where you specify the path to your jar file. As Gilbert pointed out, you can get the idea when you read the Webswing documentation https://www.webswing.org/docs/20.1/start/quickstart.html